# Sidekiq is not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq for sending mails in background.
And i am getting this in sidekiq log

```
  def performed?
    create_activation_digest &&
    customer.save &&
    send_mail(:account_activation, { email: customer.email, activation_token: customer.activation_token }) # from here mailer method is being called
  end

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'lavo@cactimedia.biz'
  layout 'mailer'
  before_action :initialize_defaults

  private

  def initialize_defaults
    @greeting = "Dear User,"
    @signature = "The Lavo Team"
  end
end

class NotificationsMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(args={})
    activation_token = args[:activation_token]
    email = args[:email]
    @activation_link = edit_api_activation_url(activation_token, email: email)

    mail(to: email)
  end
end

[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [2797cd49-dabe-4af0-a5a8-c47ae5e956b3] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "NotificationsMailer", "password_digest", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x00000007281480 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://lavo-laundry/Customer/6>>
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [2797cd49-dabe-4af0-a5a8-c47ae5e956b3] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) in 0.97ms
```

But mail are not being sent. Does somebody have any idea if i am missing something?

Comment: Can you add some more code where you are actually sending mails with sidekiq?

Comment: Edited a question, added mailer method.

Comment: Can you also add the code of your sidekiq job where you are calling this mailer?

Comment: Did you try `.deliver` at the end of send_mail() ?

Comment: Yes i tried, I found mail is not sent. But i can see in rails log as -

[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: e91ccd3f-059d-4be1-97e1-c77d6aeb9761) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "NotificationsMailer", "account_activation", "deliver_now", {:email=>"palash12@yopmail.com", :activation_token=>"d60b4251f1424ae1b2a1be1430e590ee"}
And in Sidekiq log :

[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [e91ccd3f-059d-4be1-97e1-c77d6aeb9761] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) in 0.69ms

Comment: then you better check mailer configuration, can you share the same?

Comment: The same smtp configuration is working on development environment without sidekiq. I believe there is problem with sidekiq.
I am new to it, can you please tell me how i can debug it? Like in delayed job i can check directly in active record. But what how to check error in sidekiq?

Comment: ohh, i see.. I have been working with delayed job only. I don't know if you have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743450/sidekiq-and-rails-4-actionmailer-never-delivers-emails

Comment: Try sidekiq inline mode just to verify if your code is working. With Inline mode it doesn't enqueue job. It executes it immediately.  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Answer (score 2):

Checks if the sidekiq settings have the following:

```
# config / sidekiq.yml
---
:queues:
  - mailers
```

or starts the sidekiq service with:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

as demonstrated at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#action-mailer